# How to check if more than one select box is selected

Tags: php, html, forms

I have four select boxes in a form. The user must select a value only from one select box and it doesn't matter which of the four ones. Given the fact that I can't use JS (would be easier) and that each select box has its own name, how can I check if only one of them is selected?

For example if only one is selected its ok. But if there's more than one selected I want to display an error.

I'm thinking about writing a couple of if() statements, but I'm actually looking for a more elegant solution.

I'm using PHP.

Here's a form sample:

```
<select name="hr_id">
    <option value="1">...</option>
</select>

<select name="pr_id">
    <option value="1">...</option>
</select>

<select name="dev_id">
    <option value="1">...</option>
</select>

<select name="sales_id">
    <option value="1">...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why not use radio buttons which have this functionality by default?

Comment: check the name attribute: name="selected[]", or better yet as meouw states use a radio button!

Comment: Because for each select box I have a different kind of information. @Drewdin: I said I can't use JS.

Comment: A select box is designed to let a user pick one option from several. Four select boxes are designed to let a user pick four options from four sets. Why do you have four select boxes and not one? Use 4 `<optgroup>`s to group options.

Comment: i think there is some confusion with what you're trying to do. could you post a simplified version of your form for us to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(($_POST['hr_id']+$_POST['pr_id']+$_POST['dev_id']+$_POST['sales_id'])!=1) {
 $error=true;
}
```

EDIT: I suppose this isn't exactly flexible enough. You could also do something like:

```
$fields = array('hr_id','pr_id','dev_id','sales_id');
$i=0;
foreach($fields as $k->$v) {
    $i = ($_POST[$v]!="" ? ++$i : $i );
}
$error = ($i == 1 ? false : true);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem right. What if I select an item from "sales_id" with value="125"? :)

Comment: I was just going of the sample. All of the values are 1, in this case it would work, in your "125" case it would not.

Comment: Thanks jfable, but unfortunately not all the values are "1".

Comment: The second set of edited code should work regardless of the value. Any value would increment the counter and any counter value other than 1 would throw an error. You might want to change $_POST[$v]!="" to !empty($_POST[$v]) or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use radio buttons which have this functionality by default?

```
<input type="radio" name="preference" value="red" /> Red<br/>
<input type="radio" name="preference" value="blue" /> Blue<br/>
<input type="radio" name="preference" value="green" /> Green<br/>
<input type="radio" name="preference" value="yellow" /> Yellow<br/>

When submitted

$preference = $_GET['preference']; //cleaning omitted
```

Comment: Because radio buttons wouldn't fit in the requirements.